# How to Confirm PostgreSQL on Ubuntu VM is communicating with External Server for Updates

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, firewall, port-scanning

I have an Ubuntu VM installed on a client's VMware system. Recently, the client's IT informed us that his firewall has been detecting consistent potential port scans to our VM's internal IP address (coming from 87.238.57.227). He asked if this was part of a known package update process on our VM.

He sent us a firewall output where we can see several instances of the port scan, but there are also instances of our Ubuntu VM trying to communicate back to the external server on port 37258 (this is dropped by the firewall).

Based on a google lookup, the hostname of the external IP address is "feris.postgresql.org", with the ASN pointing to a European company called Redpill-Linpro. As far as I can tell, they offer IT consulting services, specializing in open source software (like PostgreSQL, which is installed on our VM). I have never heard of them before though and have no idea why our VM would be communicating with them or vice-versa. I'm also not sure if I'm interpreting the IP lookup information correctly: https://ipinfo.io/87.238.57.227

I'm looking for a way to confirm or disprove that this is just our VM pinging for a standard postgres update. If that's the case I'd like to restrict this behaviour. We would prefer to do these types of updates manually and limit the communication outside of the VM to what is strictly necessary for the functionality of our application.

**Update**

I sent an email to Redpill's abuse account. They responded quickly saying that the server should not be port scanning anyone and if it appears that way, something is wrong.

The server is part of a cluster of machines that serves [apt.postgresql.org](https://apt.postgresql.org) among other postgres download sites. I don't think we have anything like ansible or puppet installed that would automatically check for updates but I will look into that to make sure. I'm wondering if Ubuntu reaching out to update the MOTD with the number of available packages would explain why our VM is trying to reach out to the external postgres server?

The abuse rep said in any case there should only be outgoing connections from the VM, not incoming. He asked for some additional info so I will keep communicating with him and try to update this post accordingly

Comment: Postgres does not 'phone home' to check for updates. The only way your PG would be getting updated is via apt/dpkg, which would be talking to Ubuntu, not postgres, servers. I don't know what's going on - my first guess would be that the IP in question is compromised, but I doubt that's the case as it appears to be a legit PG-project server, which I would assume is probably well-monitored.

Comment: This is very helpful information, thanks @AdamKG! There is an abuse email listed for Redpill-Linpro on the lookup site so I think I'll reach out to them and see if they can shed any light on this.
In the meantime I wonder if there's any way to narrow down the cause or source of the communication in our VM. Maybe based on the port 37258? I'm not quite sure how to approach this investigation

Comment: Is the firewall allowing the incoming connections through, just logging them?  If so, then the back connection could just be an attempt to respond to the incoming.  Although I would think the firewall log would distinguish a response packet from a new connection packet.

Comment: The "Firewall Action" listed on the incoming connections is "NA". I was assuming that means "Not Applicable" as in no action was taken - but it's possible I'm misinterpreting that. The outgoing connection has a FW Action of "drop", so looks like all the outgoing connections are stopped. I wish I could post the output but I want to be very careful not to share any info specific to the client

Comment: @user2437443 was there any more info you can share here? getting into the same scenario

Comment: Sorry @karthikeayan - my communication with the client IT dropped off at some point so I didn't get a definitive answer. But I posted an answer with some of the info we did manage to gather

Answer (score 1):

My communication with the client's IT dropped off so I did not get a definitive answer on this, but I'll provide some new details:

I reached out to the abuse email for Redpill-Linpro. He got back to me and confirmed the server corresponding to the detected IP address is part of a cluster that hosts postgres download sites, including [apt.postgresql.org](https://apt.postgresql.org). He was surprised to learn we had detected a port scan from their server and seems eager to figure out why that is happening.

He asked if the client IT could pass along some necessary info for them to set up tracking on that server. But the client IT never got back to me. I think he was satisfied that it wasn't malicious and stopped pursuing it.

Here's one of the messages the abuse rep sent me that may be relevant:

> That does look a lot like the tcp to the apt download server yes. It's
> strange that your firewall reports that many incoming connections, but
> they could be fallout from some connection tracking that's not
> operating as intended. The timing appears to be matching up more or
> less perfectly. And there should definitely not be any ping-back
> connections from it.
>
> Since you appear to be using the http version of the server (and not https) bringing the data in cleartext, they should be able to just
> dump the TCP connection contents and verify exactly what it does. But
> I bet they are going to see a number of http requests initiated by the
> apt client that is checking for updates.